# Google App engine flex Responding slow Receiving 502 (BadGateway)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google App engine Flex project is responding very slow.
and  displaying below error 
**Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.**

## 1) Output of running tracert to your application:

Tracing route to [216.239.36.21]
over a maximum of 30 hops

```
1  2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1] 
2  6 ms     2 ms     3 ms  175.139.167.254
3     4 ms     5 ms    10 ms  10.55.49.15
4     7 ms     5 ms     6 ms  10.55.48.66
5    24 ms     7 ms     6 ms  72.14.197.66
6     8 ms     9 ms     9 ms  108.170.250.10
7    21 ms    20 ms    20 ms  64.233.175.109
8    18 ms    15 ms    17 ms  108.170.225.101
9    20 ms    18 ms    18 ms  74.125.37.249
10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
19    25 ms    24 ms    24 ms  any-in-2415.1e100.net [216.239.36.21]
```

Trace complete.

2)  app.yaml is as follows

```
runtime: java
env: flex
manual_scaling:
instances: 1
health_check:
enable_health_check: False
handlers:
- url: /.*
script: this field is required, but ignored
resources:
cpu: 1
memory_gb: 4.0
disk_size_gb: 10
```

**Application logs . I would like to highlight that few of the endpoints shows 200 or 304 status in GAE logs buts Google Chrome Developer console shows 502 status**

For Example *jquery.loading.min.js* shows either 304 or 200 on GAE logs but on chrome developer console it display status as 502(Bad gateway)

Comment: Have you checked that the region of your deployment is not so far away from your physical location?

Comment: @Ggrimaldo Yes I checked the region distance , there is no latency issue. The application is working fine a week back this question is asked. Surprisingly the issue got resolved automatically after 1week without any fix being applied.